# VBScript Activate open Excel spreadsheet without URL

Tags: excel, vbscript

I have a project where the application will be used for multiple spreadsheets and naming formats are always going to be different. They want me to use *File → Open* from the menu to open a window where they select the spreadsheet from their desktop. I've got the VBScript code for that, but I can't activate the workbook to gather, or enter, data.

```
WShell.SendKeys "%FO"

objExcel.Wait (Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 3))

For i = 1 to 3
   WShell.SendKeys "+{TAB}"
Next

WShell.SendKeys "{HOME}"
WShell.SendKeys "D"
WShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"

MsgBox "Please select the file you want to open, then click OK to continue.", _
    vbOKOnly+vbSystemModal, "Open File"

WShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"

Set objWorkbook = ThisWorkbook

objWorkbook.Sheets(1).Activate
objWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1).Value = "Hello"
```

I want `Set objWorkbook = ThisWorkbook` to activate the current workbook without having to use its name or URL. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff836226.aspx

Comment: What Scott said. Whenever your solution involves `SendKeys` there's a good chance that you took a wrong turn somewhere and need to go back and re-architect your solution.

Comment: Thank you both, but when I use the link in Scott's comment, I run into an error in the `For...Next` loop when it gets to `Next lngCount`. I'm thinking there has to be more to it, or it's because it's a VBA solution when I'm using VBScript as an external script in Macro Express Pro.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to get it to work. I needed to cycle through any open Excel spreadsheets to see if the one I just opened was available. **NOTE: This only works for one spreadsheet open, which is the one opened by the Open dialog box.**

```
WShell.SendKeys "%FO"

objExcel.Wait (Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 3))

For i = 1 to 3
    WShell.SendKeys "+{TAB}"
Next

WShell.SendKeys "{HOME}"
WShell.SendKeys "D"
WShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"

MsgBox "Please select the file you want to open, then click OK to continue.", _
vbOKOnly+vbSystemModal, "Open File"

WShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"

On Error Resume Next
   Set objExcel = GetObject(,"Excel.Application")
   If Err.Number <> 0 Then ShowError ("Macro failed to get Excel object.")
On Error GoTo 0

objExcel.Wait (Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1))

For Each WB In objExcel.Workbooks
    Set objWorkbook = WB
Next

objWorkbook.Sheets(1).Activate
objWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1).Value = "Hello"
```

This will take the open spreadsheet and enter "Hello" in cell A1.