# vbscript to detect and activate open excel spreadsheet

Tags: excel, vbscript

I'm working on a project that is a VBScript ran from Macro Express. Each user of this macro will have two spreadsheets open (as shown in the image below):

[image]

The user will run the macro from the ERA SURF Assignment workbook, which will gather data from this spreadsheet and enter it into the UBH Gatekeeper Statistics workbook.

The issue I'm having is getting the macro to recognize either of the workbooks on demand.

If I use this code from [VBScript Activate open Excel spreadsheet without URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43458987/vbscript-activate-open-excel-spreadsheet-without-url), I will be able to gather/enter data, but it only does it for the last workbook open.

If I use the following code, it will stop once ERA SURF Assignment is found, but, once again, only pulls up the last workbook open:

```
For Each i In Application.Workbooks
    BookNames = i.Name
    If InStr(BookNames, "ERA SURF Assignment") Then
        AppActivate (BookNames)
    End If
Next i
```

I feel like I need a combination of the two, but also a way to specifically single out the workbook I want. Any suggestions?

**UPDATE:**

Okay, I've done a bit more research and it's a little more complex than I thought. I've come up with the following code. If there's no Excel workbook open, it will throw the 429 error code. I've found that, if there's another Excel workbook open other than the ones I want, I will get a 9 error code. The issue is if I arrange my code one way, it will recognize the 9 code when the file I want is open, or it will try to activate the desired workbook when it's not open. Am I missing something?

```
Set xl = Nothing
On Error Resume Next
   Set xl = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")   ' Attempt to attach to running Excel instance
   If Err Then
      If Err.Number = 429 Then
         MsgBox "Neither workbooks are open (Excel is not running)." & vbNewLine & "Macro will attempt to open workbooks."
         Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
         objExcel.Visible = True 'Making an Excel Object visible
         Set BookA = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(File1)  'Opening an Excel file1
         Set BookB = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(File2)  'Opening an Excel file2
         Set xl = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")   'attach to running Excel instance
      Else
         MsgBox Err.Description & " (0x" & Hex(Err.Number) & ")"
      End If
   End If

   BookA.Activate
   If Err.Number = 9 Then
      Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
      objExcel.Visible = True 'Making an Excel Object visible
      Set BookA = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(File1)  'Opening an Excel file1
   Else
      AppActivate "ERA SURF Assignment"
      objExcel.Visible = True 'Making an Excel Object visible
   End If

   BookB.Activate
   If Err.Number = 9 Then
      Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
      objExcel.Visible = True 'Making an Excel Object visible
      Set BookB = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(File2)  'Opening an Excel file2
   Else
      AppActivate "UBH Gatekeeper Statistics"
      objExcel.Visible = True 'Making an Excel Object visible
   End If
On Error GoTo 0
```

Comment: If you can have users save both files in the same folder and make sure they know not to change the filename then you can use the `Application.ActiveWorkbook.FullName` to get the path and then define `Workbooks(Path.Name.xls)'   .

Comment: The business using the macro want both workbooks already open. The ERA SURF Assignment changes daily, so it can't be hard coded into the VBScript.

Comment: It's fine if they are both open. Could they both be saved in the same folder so that they have the same filepath?

Comment: I suppose they could be saved to the same, or different, folders and called by path name when needed. Both docs have to be saved eventually once the data is entered. I've got code for this...I'll give it a try. Thanks.

Comment: The code you've listed above seems like a combination of `vba` and `vbscript` - `vbscript` wouldn't recognise the `Application` object you've referenced and `vba` wouldn't recognise the `AppActivate`...